# Mailchimp marketing api v3 - automate population and sending of a camapaign from a template via API

Tags: mailchimp-api-v3.0

I only have use of the Marketing API, not the transactional one.

I can send a campaign that is set up via the web UI through the (Send campaign - Post: /campaigns/{campaign_id}/actions/send) API end point.

What I need to understand is the principles of how to automate the sending of a campaign based on a template that I can push the email addresses of the recipients into without using the web UI.

Is the process as follows?:

1.Tag all the members you are going to send the campaign to (Add or remove member tags - Post: /lists/{list_id}/members/{subscriber_hash}/tags)

2.Create a new (Add segment Post: /lists/{list_id}/segments) or update an existing (Update segment - Patch: /lists/{list_id}/segments/{segment_id}) segment with the Tag(s) that hold(s) the email addresses of the intended recipients

3.Create a campaign using a template via the (Add campaign - Post: /campaigns) end point adding the required template ID  to the "template_id":0

4. Update the campaign (Update campaign settings - Patch: /campaigns/{campaign_id}) recipients via the"saved_segment_id"
5. Then I can send the campaign via the API (Post: /campaigns/{campaign_id}/actions/send)

I have been able to do most of the individual steps in isolation but I am not quite sure I have understood how to create the different elements, or in what order, and pull them all together to send a campaign via the Marketing API